# How to grouping window on esper (I would like esper to create windows by each group.)

Tags: java, esper

I would like esper to create windows by each group.

```
select name, sum(val) from SampleEvent.win:length(5) group by name
```

[It work like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvFQY.png)

[I want that it work like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYgKB.png)

Can I implements like this using esper? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is done with contexts in Esper. Contexts define the life cycle of analysis.

Its not clear from the picture what the condition is that starts and ends each of these boxes or whether these boxes overlap each other (overlapping context) or the boxes don't overlap (non-overlapping context). Here is something you can start with.

```
create context BlueOrRedBox start MyEvent(...some criteria...) end MyEvent(...whatever...);
context BlueOrRedBox select somekey, count(*) from MyEvent group by somekey output snapshot when terminated;
```

Replace "start MyEvent(...some criteria...)" by whatever starts a box. 
Replace "end MyEvent(...whatever...)" by whatever ends the box. 
Possibly if the start or end criteria are derived from some aggregation such as a count then use a separate statement to detect start and/or end criteria and use "insert into".

Doc links:

1. [Non-Overlapping context doc](http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.1.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#context_def_nonoverlapping)
2. [Solution patterns page](http://www.espertech.com/esper/solution-patterns/)

Comment: context!! It's new knowledge for me.
Thank you very very much.